# Return back the n inserted rows in a database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, json

I am trying to echo last 5 inserted rows of db one by one and then print it through jquery plugin . For example into the input area to be inserted last row then print then last row -1 then print etc..
in my html i have these inputs in my printablearea

```
<li><input type="number" min=1 name="printmultiple" value="1" id="printmultiple"/></li>
<div id="printableArea">
<div align="center">



<h4></h4>
<h4></h4>



<input type="text" name="barcode2"  id="barcode2" required readonly >
<input type="text" name="barcodecountry" id="barcodecountry"  >
<input type="text" name="barcodecountry" id="barcodecountry2"  >

<br>
 <div id="print">
</div>

<label id="idbar">id.:</label><input type="text" name="barcodesurname" id="barcodesurname"  required readonly>
<br>
<br>
<label id="pricebar">price:</label><input type="text" name="barcodename" id="barcodename"  required readonly>
<input type="text" name="barcodecountry" id="barcodecountry3">
</div> 
</div>
```

then in my php i am inserting multiple values depending of the value of input printmultiple

```
<?php
require('config.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
include("auth.php");


$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
    // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array
      if (empty($_POST['surname']))
        $errors['surname'] = 'Surname is required.';
      if (empty($_POST['name']))
        $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';



// return a response ===========================================================

    // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
    if ( ! empty($errors)) {

        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

$printmultiple = $_POST['printmultiple'];
$signintime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$surname =mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['surname']);
$name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['name']);
$seat= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['seat']);
$mail= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['mail']);
$ticketprice=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ticketprice']);
$barcode=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['barcode']);
$matchtype=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['matchtype']);
$telephone= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['telephone']);
$expdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+36000);
$submittedby = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION["username"]);

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT customid FROM `salonika` ORDER BY `customid` DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$max=$row['customid'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO salonika (surname, name, telephone,customid,seat,mail,ticketprice,barcode,expdate,submittedby,signintime) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

for ($i=0; $i<$printmultiple; $i++) {
    $barcode=$barcode+1;
    $seat=$seat;
    $mail=$mail;
    $ticketprice=$ticketprice;
    $expdate=$expdate;
    $submittedby=$submittedby;
    $signintime=$signintime;
    $max=$max+1;
    $surname = $surname;
    $name = $name;
    $telephone = $telephone;
    $stmt->bind_param('sssississss', $surname, $name, $telephone, $max,$seat,$mail,$ticketprice,$barcode,$expdate,$submittedby,$signintime);

    $stmt->execute();


}

$stmt->close();


        // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';



    }

    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data);
```

in my js file i have this

```
var formData = {
            'surname'       : $('input[name=surname]').val(),
            'name'      : $('input[name=name]').val(),

            'telephone' : $("#telephone").val(),
            'mail' : $("#mail").val(),
            'barcode' : $("#barcode").val(),
            'customid' : $("#customid").val(),
            'ticketprice' : $("#ticketprice").val(),
            'seat' : $("#seat").val()

        };
        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData,// our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {


                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data); 

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                if ( ! data.success) {
                        if (data.errors.surname) {
                        $('#surname-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#surname-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.surname + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                        }
                        else if (data.errors.name) {
                        $('#name-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                        }



                } else {
                    $('#printableArea').print();
                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
                     window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000);
```

is there any way to print to the printer one by one last inserted rows?

Comment: You could query the table just after the insert operation and get the last 5 rows

Comment: it's not that difficult

Comment: i am not trying to echo results to a table but to be inserted in the pritablearea div for printing to the printer one by one

Comment: You say: I am trying to echo last 5 inserted rows of db one by one and then print it through jquery plugin

Comment: yes the jquery plugin prints the content of the div to the printer

Comment: `select * from table order by id desc limit 5`, the actual output/display logic would haven't change at all.

Comment: i have one printable area i want to fill the inputs with the last row then print then last row -1 then print last row -2 then print etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code after `$stmt->close();`, according to your question here I simply build a query and execute it fetching the last `$printmultiple` rows, that the user inserts.

Then it passes an entry called `added` to the response that you can handle in your jQuery response `.done` function.

```
$printmultiple = intval($printmultiple); //sanitize variable
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `salonika` ORDER BY `customid` DESC LIMIT ".$printmultiple);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


// show a message of success and provide a true success variable
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Success!';
$data['added'] = $rows;
```

The data sent back to jQuery is encoded in `JSON` format.

Finally the JS part would be as follows:

```js
if ( data.success) {  
  //success
  $.each(data.added, function (i,it){
   alert(data.added[i]);
  });
  $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>'); 
  
  
}else{
  //code if error
       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

Comment: TypeError: item is null

Comment: do a print_r($jqueryData); in php and post it here

Comment: in php after $data[..]

Comment: undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined

Comment: no errors but no visible data in html and also the  $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>'); is not executed

Comment: echo json_encode($data); ? yes i have it in my php file

Comment: post the contents of  console.log(data);

Comment: Object { success: true, message: "Success!", added: Object }

Comment: post the contents of console.log(data.added);

Comment: Object { 0: "7784", 1: "2016-10-18 23:16:01.000000", 2: "16221458721646", 3: "2016-10-19", 4: "8", 5: "normal", 6: null, 7: "admin", 8: "DASDSADAS", 9: "7884", 18 more… }

Comment: It works, just parse that object and populate the table you need

Comment: can you provide an example how to do that ? sorry i am new

Comment: and also why after your function $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>'); is not executed although all are good

Comment: alert returns undefined